# Readonly Value not set in IE 11

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, internet-explorer

Hello this question may sound repeated, but I wasn't able to find the correct answer even after looking through a lot of posts. I have a "read only" field in my app that is set using the data entered in to the other fields.

```
<input type=“number” class=“form-control” value=“{{it.depth.value*it.width.value*it.height.value}}“readonly>
```

It works in chrome but fails in IE 11 i.e. it doesn't display anything. Does anybody know why is that so, I know angular support was stopped from previous IE versions but I am using IE11 and it still doesn't work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readonly` input element doesn't work in IE old versions. Use `disabled` instead.

```
<input type=“number” class=“form-control” value=“{{it.depth.value*it.width.value*it.height.value}}“ disabled>
```

You can also try with `readonly="readonly"` for the `input` element:

```
<input type=“number” class=“form-control” value=“{{it.depth.value*it.width.value*it.height.value}}“ readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=“number” class=“form-control” value=“{{it.depth.value*it.width.value*it.height.value}}“ [attr.readonly]="true">
```

As of now for me it working in IE11 , ca you check and let know if this is working for you.